# Подсветка синтаксиса Django template вне Django проекта

Tags: python, pycharm, django

Стоит PyCharm 3.1. Если в нём создать Django проект, то в рамках этого проекта в html файлах синтаксис Django template подсвечивается/подсказывается на ура. Но вот если создать не Django проект, то подсветки нет. Как её настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Settings - Project Settings - Python Template Languages можете выбрать синтаксис шаблонов. Проект при этом не обязательно должен быть на Django, и вообще на Python.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Так действительно работает. А можно ли такое провернуть для IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Не знаю, Идеей не пользовался

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Посмотрите [плагины](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5026?pr=pycharm) на сайте PyCharm. С помощью них можно расширить возможности среды.

Comment: В том то и дело, что pycharm с поддержкой django уже стоит.